# send CURL request with header option to get access token in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, curl, drupal-7, libcurl

I am trying to send to pass some key through curl to get response from stripe.com but not getting any response .I am using drupal 7.Is there any another way to send request through curl in drupal 7 or not i have tried two type of curl to send information to stripe which is-

1=

> curl --header "X-MyHeader: 123" https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token
>   -H Authorization: Bearer pk_test_1kWTYDiLtPzkgR32GyKtVmtu -d
>   code=ac_14Afk3MMwXCdQD12OlsyRpXEgWupv9Il -d
>   grant_type=authorization_code

2=

```
$request = array('-H Authorization'=>'pk_test_1kWTYDiLtPzkgR32GyKtVmtu','');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
$res=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close();
print_r($response);
```

?>
Please make me clear what i am doing wrong

Comment: i got this tesing curl after getting authenticated code on stripe.comcurl --header "X-MyHeader: 123" https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token -H Authorization: Bearer pk_test_1kWTYDiLtPzkgR32GyKtVmtu -d code=ac_14Afk3MMwXCdQD12OlsyRpXEgWupv9Il -d grant_type=authorization_code

Answer (score 0):

please change `print_r($response);` to `print_r($res);`